# Is there an opposite method of "in?" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there an opposite method `in?` in Rails?

```
3.in?([1,2,3])
#=> true
```

Currently, I'm using `[1,2,3].exclude?(3)` or `!3.in?([1,2,3])`.

Is there a method like `3.out_of([1,2,3])`?

Comment: Why not the `exclude?` version? That looks fine, especially if `[1,2,3]` is fairly constant.

Comment: Of course, I use it with variables. As you say I choose `exclude?` when I want to check if an array doesn't include a value, but sometimes I want to check if a value is not in a list.

Comment: I think you're describing the same thing two different ways. If A is not in list B (`!a.in?(b)`), then list B does not contain item A (`!b.include?(a)` or `b.exclude?(a)`).

Comment: yes, the logic is the same. The way how to describe is important. I think that's why `b.exclude?` is implemented in rails even though `!b.include?` already exists.

Comment: Note that if you need to write `...if !3.in?([1,2,3])`, but prefer to avoid the negation, you may be able to write `...unless 3.in?([1,2,3])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such method. If there were, it would be defined here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.2.1/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/inclusion.rb).